# MariaDB io_uring_queue_init() failed with errno 1 with kernel version 6.2.0-1018

Tags: linux, docker, mariadb, linux-kernel, io

I am running MariaDB using the official docker hub image: mariadb:lts

(this is MariaDB 10.11.6-MariaDB-1:10.11.6+maria~ubu2204 source revision fecd78b83785d5ae96f2c6ff340375be803cd299)

When the container starts I got the following message:

```
[Warning] mariadbd: io_uring_queue_init() failed with errno 1
[Warning] InnoDB: liburing disabled: falling back to innodb_use_native_aio=OFF
```

I do understand that the second warning is the consequence of the first, and also know I can prevent this by configuring `innodb_use_native_aio=OFF`

However I would like to have high performance async I/O

I've checked the container's kernel version with `uname -r` it is **6.2.0-1018-azure** same as the docker host's.

```
$ uname -a 
Linux vm-ubuntu-90 6.2.0-1018-azure #18~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 21 19:25:02 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```